# Hide Amazon Cart Using userContent.css

Tags: css

I'm trying to hide the Amazon cart (the "panel" on the right hand side).  It makes Christmas shopping for your family more challenging.

I thought I could put something like this in my userContent.css;

```
@-moz-document domain(amazon.com) {
    #nav-flyout-ewc { display: none !important; }
}
```

But so far I'm not having much luck.

I'm using Firefox:

```
Version 82.0.2
Build ID 20201027185343
Distribution ID canonical
```

And the userContent.css is in the "chrome" folder in my Profile Directory as reported by about:support

Comment: It seems I need to set toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets to true in the about:config.  The space for the cart is still there, but at least the contents are no longer visible.

Comment: Adding `body { padding-right: 0 !important; }` closed up the space, even if it does seem a bit heavy handed.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a bit of a dive trying to sort this out myself and (like you) wasn't satisfied with just blanket bombing the body. Here's my solution (*which in the process of finding, helped me realise I didn't have to do it for the subdomain '`smile.`', too*):

```
@-moz-document domain(amazon.co.uk) {
    #nav-flyout-ewc { display:none !important; }
    .nav-ewc-persistent-hover.a-js body { padding-right: 0px !important; }
    .nav-ewc-persistent-hover body { padding-right: 0px !important; }
}
```

You would obviously just change this to '`.com`' or, if you wish to affect multiple sites, then, this:

```
@-moz-document domain(amazon.com), domain(amazon.co.uk) {
    #nav-flyout-ewc { display:none !important; }
    .nav-ewc-persistent-hover.a-js body { padding-right: 0px !important; }
    .nav-ewc-persistent-hover body { padding-right: 0px !important; }
}
```